# sequelize nested include result set parent object

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize-cli

I have multiple includes in single query of sequelize but I can't get the result as I want. please refer below code

```
const users = await User.findAll({
  include: {
    model: Tool,
    as: 'Instruments',
    include: {
      model: Teacher,
      include: [ /* etc */ ]
    }
  }
});
```

output:

```
[{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "id": 1,
  "Instruments": [{ // 1:M and N:M association
    "name": "Scissor",
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "Teacher": { // 1:1 association
      "name": "Jimi Hendrix"
    }
  }]
}]
```

now I want output like

```
    [{
      "name": "John Doe",
      "id": 1,
      "Instruments": { // 1:M and N:M association
        "name": "Scissor",
        "id": 1,
        "userId": 1
      },
      "Teacher": { // 1:1 association
        "name": "Jimi Hendrix"
      }
    }]
```

It's possible if yes then how ??

Comment: What do you want if the `Instruments` array has more element ?

Comment: no Instruments array has not more element I want just set Teacher object to each parent object

Answer (score 0):

As the relation stated

**USER** (m)------(n) **INSTRUMENTS** (1)------(1) **TEACHER**

So

1. Every single instruments has a teacher and every teacher teaches an instrument.
2. Every single user can learn multiple instrument and every instrument can learn by multiple users.

Based on these relation between `USER` and `TEACHER` is following

**USER** (m)------(n) **TEACHER**

1. Every single user can learn instrument from multiple teacher.
2. Every single teacher can teach instrument multiple user.

Your original output was

```
[{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "id": 1,
  "Instruments": [{ // 1:M and N:M association
    "name": "Scissor",
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "Teacher": { // 1:1 association
      "name": "Jimi Hendrix"
    }
  }]
}]
```

What do you expect if there is multiple instrument ? like following

```
[{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "id": 1,
  "Instruments": [{ // 1:M and N:M association
    "name": "Scissor",
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "Teacher": { // 1:1 association
      "name": "Jimi Hendrix"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Guitar",
    "id": 2,
    "userId": 1,
    "Teacher": {
      "name": "john wick"
    }
  }]
}]
```

If you make flat of `instrument` then you always can post processing of your result after receiving from sequelize.

```js
const result = [{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "id": 1,
  "Instruments": [{ // 1:M and N:M association
    "name": "Scissor",
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "Teacher": { // 1:1 association
      "name": "Jimi Hendrix"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Guitar",
    "id": 2,
    "userId": 1,
    "Teacher": {
      "name": "john wick"
    }
  }]
}]

console.log(result.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.Instruments.map(function(iObj) {
      const teacher = iObj.Teacher;
      delete iObj.Teacher;
      return {
        name: obj.name,
        id: obj.id,
        Instrument: iObj,
        Teacher: teacher
      }
    });
}).flat())
```